# Postgresql backup cron job using the script from the wiki

Tags: postgresql, backup, cron-task

I am trying to use the scripts from the posgresql wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux
as an automated solution in a cronjob. My main problem is that the script asks for the password. Thus automation is not possible.

I read in multiple places that you can create a ".pgpass" which can solve all problems. So I created the file containing this info:

```
# file: .pgpass
# hostname:port:database:username:password
localhost:5432:DB:postgres:"supersecretpassword"
```

and changed the rights to 0600 (chmod 0600 /.pgpass).

But it didn't change the outcome at all I located it in several places with no success (root, script folder, ...)

My second problem is that I want to use the entire script backing up everything having multiple daily and weekly backups and from what I understand this only allows to use the password for one single database (DB)

Comment: in which folder have you created the .pgpass? have you tried `/home/user/.pgpass`?

Comment: Is your database really named 'DB'?  What error do you get?  Can you connect with `psql` using the password for?

Answer (score 0):

of couse I entered the correct database name and password. but I want to backup everything (using the script  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)
I got one copy of .pgpass in /home/ (there is no subfolder in /home/) and one in the folder where I got my script right now (/var/www/backup_scripts/)

If I start the script It asks me 3 times for a password:

```
Performing globals backup
--------------------------------------------

Globals backup
Passwort:

Performing schema-only backups
--------------------------------------------

Passwort für Benutzer postgres:
Performing full backups
--------------------------------------------

Passwort für Benutzer postgres:
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets just make a pretend case I got 2 postgress databases called blogDB and shopDB.
What I want is a new user called backup user with a password: "supersecretpassword"
which is set as backup user in the pg_backup.config file
and a cronjob running the rotating script once a day so my database backups won't fill my server diskspace.
How would I do this. Ideally I should be notified if an error occours during backup.